# Problema con el uso de políticas en laravel (policies)

Tags: laravel-5, backend

Hola estoy utilizando laravel y tengo un error con el uso de las políticas, estoy tratando de que solo el usuario autenticado pueda editar su perfil, pero me deniega el acceso.

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $user =\App\User::findOrFail($id);
    $this->authorize($user);      
    return view('users.edit',compact('user'));

}
```

Aquí es donde comparo al usuario logueado

```
public function edit(User $authUser, User $user){

    return $authUser->id === $user->id;

}
```

Y este es el error que me arroja

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException thrown  with message "This action is unauthorized."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando el authorize mal. Estás pasando solo un parámetro cuando son dos. Recuerda siempre que el primero es la acción que quieres autorizar y el segundo el modelo al que deseas acceder.

En tu ejemplo quedaría `$this->authorize('edit', $user);`

Answer (score 0):

La solución mas simple es

```
public function edit($id)
{

    if(Auth::check()){ // COMPRUEBAS SI HAY LOGIN
       if(Auth::user()->id == $id){  // COMPRUEBAS QUE EL ID POR PARAMETRO SEA IGUAL QUE EL ID DEL USUARIO
         $user =\App\User::findOrFail($id);
          return view('users.edit',compact('user'));
       }
    }

    return redirect()->to($url); // AQUI PUEDES PONER UNA VISTA DE ERROR

}
```

Comment: sí resulto, pero me gustaría usar las policies